# TypeScript: Promise of type 'Message'|'Message[]', but ensuring type is 'Message'

Tags: typescript

Right now, I have got a method that returns a Promise of `Message | Message[]`. I'm casting the type to `Message` via:

```
message.say('meow')
    .then((msg: Message|Message[]) => {
        (msg as Message).react('meow');
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

But, I'm not sure if this is a good practice or if I should be doing this in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Message` is a class you could test the type of `msg` using `instanceof`.

```
message.say('meow')
  .then((msg: Message|Message[]) => {
    if (msg instanceof Message)
      msg.react('meow');
    else
      msg.forEach(x => x.react('meow'));
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

This is safer and most IDEs will provide helpful code completion as each branch of the `if` statement narrows the type of `msg`.